# How to handle multiple rows fulfilling criteria when joining Oracle tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Given a table of roles, companies and a employee table where we store for each employee which role he/she has at each company.
I'm trying to create a view which indicates for each combination of role and company and employee by a ‘Y’ or ‘N’ in the “checked_yn” column, whether this employee has this role at this company.

```
company table
----------------
|ID | name      |
-----------------
| 1 |    A      |
| 2 |    B      |
-----------------

roles table
-------------
|ID | role  |
-------------
| 1 |   X   |
| 2 |   Y   |
| 3 |   Z   |
-------------

employee table
----------------------------------------------
|ID | company_id | role_id | employee_log_id |
---------------------------------------------|
| 1 |     1      |    1    |        1        |
| 2 |     1      |    2    |        1        |
| 3 |     2      |   null  |        1        |
----------------------------------------------
```

The desired outcome is this:

```
EMPLOYEE_ROLES_VW view
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Id |company_id | role_id | Checked_yn | employee_id | employee_log_id |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1 |     1     |   1     |     Y      |      1      |         1       | 
| 2 |     1     |   2     |     Y      |      2      |         1       | 
| 3 |     1     |   3     |     N      |     null    |         1       | 
| 4 |     2     |   1     |     N      |     null    |         1       | 
| 5 |     2     |   2     |     N      |     null    |         1       | 
| 6 |     2     |   3     |     N      |     null    |         1       | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my current query:

```
with ROLES_X_COMP as (SELECT ROL.ID           AS X_ROLE_ID,
                             COM.ID           AS X_COMPANY_ID,
                      FROM ROLES ROL
                               CROSS JOIN COMPANY COM)


SELECT ROWNUM                    AS ID,
       EMP.ID                     AS SMCR_EMPLOYEE_ID,
       EMP.EMPLOYEE_LOG_ID        AS EMPLOYEE_LOG_ID,
       ROLES_X_COMP.X_ROLE_ID  ,
       EMP.ROLE_ID           AS ROLE_ID,
       ROLES_X_COMP.X_COMPANY_ID,
       EMP.COMPANY_ID        AS COMPANY_ID,
       CASE
           WHEN ROLES_X_COMP.X_ROLE_ID = SE.ROLE_ID AND ROLES_X_COMP.X_COMPANY_ID = 
SE.COMPANY_ID THEN 'Y'
           ELSE 'N' END          AS CHECKED_YN

FROM ROLES_X_COMP
         LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE EMP ON ROLES_X_COMP.X_COMPANY_ID = EMP.COMPANY_ID
```

Because of the join on EMPLOYEE “finds” the company with id=1 twice it joins twice with the cross join of role and company table. So I'm getting this result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Id |company_id | role_id | Checked_yn | employee_id | employee_log_id |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1 |     1     |   1     |     Y      |      1      |         1       | 
| 2 |     1     |   2     |     N      |      1      |         1       | 
| 3 |     1     |   3     |     N      |      1      |         1       | 

| 4 |     1     |   1     |     N      |      2      |         1       | 
| 5 |     1     |   2     |     Y      |      2      |         1       | 
| 6 |     1     |   3     |     N      |      2      |         1       | 

| 7 |     2     |   1     |     N      |      3      |         1       | 
| 8 |     2     |   2     |     N      |      3      |         1       | 
| 9 |     2     |   3     |     N      |      3      |         1       | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think a JOIN might be the wrong option here and a UNION more appropriate but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a partitioned outer join:

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT ROWNUM AS id,
       e.company_id,
       r.id AS role_id,
       NVL2( e.role_id, 'Y', 'N' ) AS CheckedYN,
       e.role_id AS employee_id,
       e.employee_log_id
FROM   roles r
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       employee e
       PARTITION BY ( e.company_id, e.employee_log_id )
       ON ( r.id = e.role_id )
```

or (depending on how you want to partition and join the data):

```sql
SELECT ROWNUM AS id,
       c.id AS company_id,
       r.id AS role_id,
       NVL2( e.role_id, 'Y', 'N' ) AS CheckedYN,
       e.role_id AS employee_id,
       e.employee_log_id
FROM   roles r
       CROSS JOIN
       company c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       employee e
       PARTITION BY ( e.employee_log_id )
       ON ( c.id = e.company_id AND r.id = e.role_id )
```

**Output**:

Both output the same for the test data but may give differing results depending on your actual data.

> ```
> ID | COMPANY_ID | ROLE_ID | CHECKEDYN | EMPLOYEE_ID | EMPLOYEE_LOG_ID
> -: | ---------: | ------: | :-------- | ----------: | --------------:
>  1 |          1 |       1 | Y         |           1 |               1
>  2 |          1 |       2 | Y         |           2 |               1
>  3 |          1 |       3 | N         |        null |               1
>  4 |          2 |       1 | N         |        null |               1
>  5 |          2 |       2 | N         |        null |               1
>  6 |          2 |       3 | N         |        null |               1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a51f9ff5bd354284caf5ed540e16751e)*

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick in db<>fiddle. If I'm applying it to my tables I'm not getting any rows for company=2 though. I probably made a copy mistake. Would you be so kind and explain how the partition in cooperation with he join work?

Comment: The query is split up into "partitions" (so in your case, each partition is a `company_id` and an `employee_log_id`) and then the `OUTER JOIN` ensured that the rows are repeated for each partition. Another example is https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227069/what-is-a-partitioned-outer-join

Comment: @P.Maino Updated with an alternate version that just partitions on `employee_log_id` and includes the `company_id` in the `OUTER JOIN`'s conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND ROLES_X_COMP.X_ROLE_ID = EMP.ROLE_ID
```

Is missing at the end of your query
But the outcome will be

```
EMPLOYEE_ROLES_VW view
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Id |company_id | role_id | Checked_yn | employee_id | employee_log_id |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1 |     1     |   1     |     Y      |      1      |         1       | 
| 2 |     1     |   2     |     Y      |      2      |         1       | 
| 3 |     1     |   3     |     N      |     null    |         null    | 
| 4 |     2     |   1     |     N      |     null    |         null    | 
| 5 |     2     |   2     |     N      |     null    |         null    | 
| 6 |     2     |   3     |     N      |     null    |         null    | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you try this out? I think (and my test seems to prove that) it still joins twice the cross join between roles and company to the employee with company=1 and one time for company=2